# Leaflet: marker icon size on geojson layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm displaying a Geojson layer with Leaflet. I would like to change de default marker icon size.

Here is the code I came up:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
                pointToLayer: function(featuer, latlng) {
                    var smallIcon = L.Icon.extend({
                        options: {
                            'iconSize': [10, 10]
                        }
                    });
                    var myIcon = new smallIcon();
                    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
                },
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });
```

However, I'm having javascript error when loading the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popupAnchor' of undefined
```

Any clues ?

Comment: have you tried it without ajax?

Comment: No I didn't. Not sure how I could do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when you extend the L.Icon class, you have to specify the IconUrl, which is the link to the image file used for the icon. See the docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon

Since the smallIcon constructor does not satisfy all the required options, myIcon will be undefined.

Try this:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaflet/images/marker-icon.png',
    iconSize: [10,10],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Or extend `L.Icon.Default` instead of `L.Icon`.

Comment: Thanks, geohacker's solution is working indeed.
However, since I don't want to override iconURL (I'm using leaflet from CDN), extending L.Icon.Default was the good way to go.
Cheers !